# How can I loop through ACF flexible content in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've created a page in Wordpress with a flexible content layout which currently includes two different blocks, however I'm struggling to understand how I can render each different block type correctly within the loop.

```
// test.tsx

const Test: FunctionComponent = ({ data }): ReactElement => {
  const { layouts } = data.wordpressPage.edges.node.acf.layouts_page;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Test" />

      <main>
        {layouts.map((layout, index) => {
          if (WordPressAcf_two_col_image_text) {
            return <TwoColImageText content={layout.content} />;
          } else if (WordPressAcf_two_col_text) {
            return <TwoColText content={layout.content} />;
          }
        })}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Test;

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    wordpressPage(slug: { eq: "test-flexible-content" }) {
        edges {
          node {
            acf {
              layouts_page {
                ... on WordPressAcf_two_col_image_text {
                  id
                  heading
                  content
                  tag
                }
                ... on WordPressAcf_two_col_text {
                  id
                  content
                  heading
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__typename` field to get the GraphQL type. This goes outside of the inline fragments since it is a shared field between all types in the union.

```
layouts_page {
  __typename

  ... on WordPressAcf_two_col_image_text {
    # …
  }
  ... on WordPressAcf_two_col_text {
    # …
  }
}
```

Then your conditional would check for identity like so:

```js
layout.__typename === "WordPressAcf_two_col_image_text"
```

There's a more elegant way to construct the whole thing than using a big inline conditional though:

```js
const typeMap = {
  WordPressAcf_two_col_image_text: TwoColImageText,
  WordPressAcf_two_col_text: TwoColText,
}

const Test: FunctionComponent = ({ data }): ReactElement => {
  const layouts = data.wordpressPage.edges.node.acf.layouts_page;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <main>
        {layouts.map(({ __typename, ...layoutProps }), index) => 
          React.createElement(typeMap[__typename], { key: index, ...layoutProps }) 
        )}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```